# git error on push : "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, dreamhost

I have **dreamhost** account and wanted to host a git repository so I followed the steps [here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Git#Setup_One:_For_the_Impatient) .

Here is the what I did:

1 - Installed **tortoisegit** and **msysgit** following the steps [here](http://dbanck.de/2009/10/08/github-windows-and-tortoisegit-part-1-installing-pulling/) (didnt generate a key)

2 - Using **Git Bash** (with username: *geryit*, host: *geryit.net*)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh geryit@geryit.net "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

then created my local and remote repositories
and

```
git remote add origin ssh://geryit@geryit.net/~/p5.git
git push origin master
```

then it asks for my **username** and **password** and after I type i got this error:

[image]

I tried assigning private **putty key** to tortoisegit but no luck.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried if normal ssh access to the server works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the git repo on the server:

```
ssh geryit@geryit.net
git init --bare ~/p5.git
```

Then exit out of geryit.net and try your push again.

You should not have to enter the password when logging into the server in the first line above.  If you are prompted for a password, this means the key setup above didn't work.

Comment: Thanks Jess, you are right. I couldnt create a repo on remote.